# Fill common attribute value from all scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have multiple scripts that have one common boolean variable with the same name. As shown below:

Script1.cs

```
public bool isTrigger = false;
```

Script2.cs

```
public bool isTrigger = false;
```

...
...

Now I have a master script, that should find all the scripts with the common boolean name and change it. Here in the example `allScripts` would be the list of all scripts that have the isTrigger boolean.

MasterScript.cs

```
for(int i = 0; i<allScripts.Length; i++){
  allScripts[i].isTrigger = true;
}
```

How do I achieve this? How do I find all the scripts that have the same boolean variable and add it to a list?

Comment: What is the type of `allScripts`?

Comment: In C#/.NET you should be using `PasacalCase` for all public members. Only use `camelCase` for parameters, locals and private fields.

Comment: @Dai allScripts is just an example of combined scripts of (Script1, Script2, ... etc.)

Comment: I want the MasterScript to find all the scripts with the common boolean name and change it.

Comment: So you don't actually have a variable named `allScripts`?

Comment: Also, C# programs are not "scripts". I know Unity is _special_, but the C# it runs is still compiled to CIL.

Comment: [**`interface`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) ! or a common base class ...

Comment: @Dai I updated my question to specify what allScripts is about.

Comment: You do not. C# source files are just text, compiled to CIL (Common Intermediate Language). If you want to find C# files that contain some variable, you have to do not so trivial string magic on all these files. Even if you did that you could not simply access this variable during runtime. What you are trying to achieve is probably unnecessary and there is a better way to do it. If you are a beginner I recommend trying to solve your problem some other way as this seems quite advanced and overkill to me.

Comment: @derHugo sorry yes all classes are MonoBehaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said there are basically two options:

#### Common Base class

Use a common base class for your components like e.g.

```
public abstract class MyBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool IsTrigger;

    // more common fields, properties and methods
}
```

and then instead inherit your other classes from that one

```
public class ClassA : MyBase
{
    // additional A specific stuff
}

public class ClassB : MyBase
{
    // additional B specific stuff
}
```

Since `ClassA` and `ClassB` aready inherit the members from `MyBase` you can then directly use

```
public class Master : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use the common base type!
    // Either populated via the Inspector
    public MyBase[] allInstances;

    // Or on runtime
    private void Awake()
    {
        // e.g. find everything of the base type in your scene
        allInstances = FindObjectsOfType<MyBase>(true);

        foreach(var instance in allInstances)
        {
            instance.IsTrigger = true;
        }
    }
}
```

- **Advantages**

  - Every subclass already has the field `IsTrigger` and there is no more to do
  - The base class can already implement common behavior in general and can be extended using [`virtual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual), [`abstract`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) and then [`override`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) in the subclasses
- **Disadvantages**

  - You can only inherit from one single class so extending this with another base class is very inflexible

---

#### Interface

Instead of a common base class you can use an [`interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface). An interface does not bring any own implementation but is rather a member template.

As in an interface you can't define fields you will have to use properties

```
public interface IMyThing
{
    bool IsTrigger { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
public class ClassA : MonoBehaviour, IMyThing
{
    // example using a serialzed auto-property
    [field: SerializeField] public bool IsTrigger { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : MonoBehaviour, IMyThing
{
    // Example using a backing field
    [SerializeField] private bool isTrigger;

    public bool IsTrigger
    {
        get => isTrigger;
        set => isTrigger = value;
    }
}
```

and then in your master

```
public class Master : MonoBehaviour
{
    // reference via Inspector
    // Using the SeriaizeReferenceAttribute enables to serialize and reference any instances of 
    // classes inheriting from UnityEngine.Object and implementing the interface
    [SeriaizeReference] public IMyThing[] allInstances;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // since FindObjectOfType can not be sued on interfaces here i gets a bit more complex
        // find all instances from all scenes
        var list = new List<IMyThing>();
    
        for (var i = 0; i < SceneManager.sceneCount; i++)
        {
            var scene = SceneManager.GetSceneAt(i);
            var roots =  scene.GetRootGameObjects( );
            foreach (var root in roots)
            {
                list.AddRange(root.GetComponentsInChildren<IMyThing>(true));
            }
        }

        allInstances = list.ToArray();

        foreach(var instance in allInstances)
        {
            instance.isTrigger = true;
        }
    }
}
```

- **Advantage**

  - Solves the limitation of the base class: You can implement as many interfaces as you wish
- **Disadvantage**

  - No guarantee anymore that a class implementing `IMyThing` is a `MonoBehaviour`! => `FindObjectsOfType` can not be used and `GetComponent`, etc might fail on runtime
  - Every class has to implement according members itself
  - Unity doesn't directly serialize interfaces

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed explanation :)

Answer (score -2):

You can create an interface in which you define your property. You then have your scripts inherited from this class.

When instantiating your objects you need to add them to a list.

```
public interface IExampleA 
{
public bool isTrigger { get; set;}
}

public class B : IExampleA 
{

}
class masterscript
{
    public void function() 
    {
     // Create objects that has class B
     // if object has class B add it to a list
     // do your loop
     }


}
```